# Changing a paragraph to a different size

Tags: css, html, fonts, size

I have a section of my website that I want the paragraph font size to be slightly bigger.

I have my body set at font:

```
body{color:#fff; font: 1em/1.6em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
```

and the paragraph in targeting I have:

```
 .inner-container p{font-size: 1.3em/1.6em ;text-align: justify; padding-left: 20px; margin-bottom: 8px;}
```

but it is being overwritten by the body is there an easy way to fix this solution or do I have to take the overall font size out of the body?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

> but it is being overwritten by the body

No, it is not.

You CSS is simply invalid - `1.3em/1.6em` is not a valid `font-size`.

That format is only valid for the `font` shorthand property. You either need to use that one (careful, it must include at least size and family, and resets other properties you do not list to default values), or specify `font-size` and `line-height` separately.

Comment: Thank you. I did not see that all fixed it there specifying the font size and line height separately.

Comment: A little tip, use your browser dev tools to inspect the element in question in such cases - in Chrome for example you will see the faulty property striked-out and with a yellow warning triangle in front of it.